# How can I view a Displacement texture on a model

Tags: texturing, workflow

I'm making some textures for use in displacement modifiers. The only way I know to view how the texture fits on a model, is it assign to a modifier, and watch how the mesh changes as a function of the texture.

Instead of watching how a modifier changes the mesh, is it possible to simply draw the texture on the surface?  Setting texture-mode in field highlighted below only seems to work for Cycles textures.

[image]

Note: I'm working with procedural textures

Comment: In your question you are asking about Blender Internal, but in the comments on the answer below you seem to be asking a different question about Cycles. Please edit your question to clarify what you are actually asking about.

Comment: Ah, I thought the textures that we create in the Texture tab from the Properties window were called "Blender Internal textures", as opposed to "Cycles textures", which we use in Cycles materials. I'm trying to refer a texture that can be dropped in a Displacement modifier - what should call it, if not a BI texture?

Comment: It's only a BI texture if you are rendering with BI. In your screenshot you just have a Displace Modifier Texture. There isn't really an official way to describe that other than referring to the modifier it's for.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much the same as in Cycles.

1. Add a light to your scene (a sun, for example)
2. Tab into edit mode, unwrap your plane
3. Add a material with a texture to your plane
4. switch 3D view to "Rendered"

[image]

[image: result]

Comment: I don't think I was clear in my question.. I'm using Cycles, but trying to develop textures to use in my modifiers. Do I really need to switch to BI to develop the textures, then switch back to Cycles after I'm done?

Comment: AFAIK there is no disadvantage to switch from Cycles to internal. I'm doing it all the time when I create game assets.